# Select-String -Context and find email address in data

Tags: powershell, variables, select-string

I have a text file where variations of this data (the number after 'SVC' and the date before, along with the text body) will appear multiple times.  I can capture the string of data, but once I do, I need to locate an email address inside that data.  The email may appear in the context at any line 4 through 9.  I can't seem to figure out how to isolate the data and set it as a variable so it can be captured.

```
Select-String $WLDir -pattern '(\d{2}:\d{2}) - (\d{2}:\d{2})(PMT[S|T]\d{8})' -Context 0,9 | ForEach-Object {
        $StartTime=[datetime]::ParseExact($_.Matches.Groups[1].Value,"HH:mm",$null)
        $EndTime=[datetime]::ParseExact($_.Matches.Groups[2].Value,"HH:mm",$null)
        $ElapsedTime = (NEW-TIMESPAN –Start $StartTime –End $EndTime).TotalHours
        $Email = Select-String $_. -pattern '(\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b)'
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        SO = $_.Matches.Groups[3].Value
        Topic = $_.Context.PostContext[0]
        Status = $_.Context.PostContext[1]
        ElapsedHrs = $ElapsedTime
        Email = $Email
    }
} | Export-Csv $ExportCsv -NoTypeInformation
```

My example file is like this:

```
  09:45 - 10:15SVC1234567 | Sev8 |437257 | COMPANY | Due: 12/28/2016
  WORK TITLE
  - - Preferred Customer (Y/N): Y Phone: 000-000-0000 ANY Hardware (Y/N): N 
  DATA on file (Y/N/NA): Y Contact: Person Name Full Address: 1234 PANTS 
  XING, RM/STE 100,NEWARK, NJ, 00000 - Hours: 8-5 Issue: Install admin 
  and others Fax Number: NA (required for all cases sent to LOCATION or 
  LOCATION_EXCPT Provider Groups) E-Mail address: email@location.com the 
  customer speak English? yes Escalation Approved By (Name/ID): Guy 
  aljdfs ITEM Product: PRODUCTNAME Group:THIS ONE Include 
  detailed notes below, including reason for severity: SCHEDULED WORK 
  ------------------------------ NOTES: -Cx requesting a tech on site -Cx 
  wants to install WS and wants to be assisted in other concerns
```

I've tried capturing the email in the context with `$Email = Select-String $_. -pattern '(\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b)'`, `$Email = Select-String $_.WLDir -pattern '(\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b)'` and `$Email = Select-String $_.Context -pattern '(\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b)'` but can't figure out how to call back the context to search it for the email address.  There's also a good chance I'm doing this all wrong.  Does anyone know how I can capture this and set it as a variable?

Comment: `$_.Context.PostContext`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I don't get an error, but my export.csv shows a blank column for "Email".  Is `$Email = Select-String $_.Context.PostContext -pattern '(\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b)'` the correct syntax?  Is there something wrong with that regex to find an email address?

Comment: $Email is a matches object not a string. Assuming it is returning something you need to extract the value first. Just like you did with the first sleect string. The brackets in your regex will make a group which is not required here.

Comment: @Matt I'm just getting blank fields in my CSV, so I'm not sure.  I get four "True" statements.  Is this statement building off MathiasR.Jessen's statement?  I tried what Mathias said with the Email field on the CSV being `Email = $Email.Matches.Groups[1]` and bombed out the entire job (blank document returned) so I am not grasping this.

Comment: @Matt I've been at this for a bit.  I have no idea how to get the value.  Can you assist?  Any chance I could convince you to copy the code and example and run it and see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's not capturing anything.  If I have it set up as `$Email = Select-String $_.Context.PostContext -pattern '(\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b)'` and I run `$Email` I get nothing, even though I can look at the text body and see the email address is in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I never found an accurate way to capture this information, I decided to capture all lines 0-9 in post context into Status.  On the Excel sheet, I'm using the calculation from [this page](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1272-excel-extract-email-address.html)  of `=IF(O6="","",TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(O6,FIND(" ",O6&" ",FIND("@",O6))-1)," ",REPT(" ",LEN(O6))),LEN(O6))))` to pull the data from column "O" to column "Q" where the email belongs.  I appreciate everyone's assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$content = gc -path $path -Raw | Out-String
$regex1 = [regex]"\w+@\w+.\w+"
$regex2=[regex]"(?ms)(\d{2}:\d{2}) - (\d{2}:\d{2})(\D+)(\d+)(.*)"
$content | Select-String -pattern $regex2 | %{
$startTime = [datetime]::ParseExact(($regex2.Matches($content) | %{$_.Groups[1].Value}),"HH:mm",$null) 
$endTime = [datetime]::ParseExact(($regex2.Matches($content) | %{$_.Groups[2].Value}),"HH:mm",$null) 
$elapsedTime = (NEW-TIMESPAN –Start $startTime –End $endTime).TotalHours
$code = "PMT" + ($_.Matches.Groups[4].value) 
$remainingString = $_.Matches.Groups[5].Value
$topic = $remainingString.split("`n")[1] 
$status = $remainingString.split("`n")[2] 
$email = $regex1.Matches($remainingString).Value    

[PSCustomObject]@{
        SO = $code
        Topic = $topic
        Status = $status
        ElapsedHrs = $elapsedTime
        Email = $email
    }
} | Export-Csv "res.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This whole thing occurs within a `ForEach` already.  If I go back and get the content of the entire file, and not just the selected string, I won't be pulling the right email address.

Comment: The for-each was to get you multiple instances of any email found and the idea was to use regex object. Try this otherwise: $_ | Select-String $regex -AllMatches | %{$_.matches} | %{$_.Value}

Comment: Like this?  `$regex = [regex]"\w+[a-zA-Z0-9]@\w+[a-zA-Z0-9].\w+"` `$Email = $_ | Select-String $regex -AllMatches | %{$_.matches} | %{$_.Value}`?   I'm putting it in the variable list under the primary `Select-String` (right below $ElapsedTime).  If that's the case, it returns nothing.

Comment: From the text, what are you trying to capture in SO, Topic and Status?

Comment: If you look at the code, I'm capturing SO as (PMT[S|T]\d{8}), which is a service order "PMT" then either "S" or "T" followed by 8 digits.  Topic is one specific line of context under the line where it finds the PMT information, Status is another line, and ElapsedHrs is a calculation of two previous regex captures.  Somewhere between lines 4 and 9, an email address will show up.  I'm trying to capture that email address and place it on the CSV with the other information under the Email header.

Comment: Edited code. Am assuming you want to prefix PMT to the 8-digit-code found in the text file. Having PMT in the pattern will fail the regex.

Comment: Thanks for trying.  This code fails as well.  It only grabs the first line's worth of data and repeats it down the CSV.  I think I'm going to give up on this project for now and try again another time.